# how to mock file copy in a functional test

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, phpunit, symfony-2.8

I have a controller which duty is copying a file passed along with the request (through a body POST) to a specific path under `web/images`. The path is specified by a property living into the specific `Controller`.

What I would like to do is testing it with a *functional test*, but I wouldn't like it to overwrite files in my project, so I would like to use `vfs` or change the path before my test case sends the request.

Is there a good-straight way to accomplish this?

Comment: *"but I wouldn't like it to overwrite files in my project"* -- this sounds like you are doing something wrong. Make sure the code writes in a directory (initially empty) that is used only for this purpose. And you do not run the tests in the production environment, do you? Finally, if you want to test *"a controller which duty is copying a file"* I think it's better to not mock the file system but use a real one. Otherwise, what do you test? The behaviour of the mock?

Comment: That's partially true, it always depends on what you need to test, let's not turn our mindset into an opinionated solution :)
If a controller's duty is overwriting a file placed in a specific path, and git traces the original default file, what I would like to test is that *a controller replaces the file* according to a specified path, but I want my dear old original default file not to be touched. What's missing is the original path that could be test on test and quality environments. But for a TDD development I think this test could be more than OK: I'm testing the behavior anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to answer myself: I refactored my code in order to have a property that specifies the path I would like to copy/overwrite my file.

Then, inside a PHPUnit class I replace the object property's value with a [vfsStream](https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream) path. By doing like that I get the behavior I need, without touching my real files/paths. Everything will live inside the virtual file system and my object will use it.

Parameters are important for a clean and reusable code, but even more when you want to unit-test: I think Unit testing is helping me to force to parameterize everything in place of relapsing to hardcoding when you don't have so much time. In order to help me writing unit tests I created a class that accesses methods and properties, irrespective of their accessibility.

[PHPUnitUtils](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/belkalab/4jbeX)

I'm quite sure there's already something more sophisticated, but this class fullfills my needs in this very moment. Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to load configuration that may change between environments as an environmental variable.  (I have not ever used symfony before, so there may be tools to help with env vars)

The upload path could then be

```
$upload_path = getenv('WEB_IMAGE_UPLOAD_PATH') ? 
    getenv('WEB_IMAGE_UPLOAD_PATH') : 'web/images'
```

This will allow you to specify a temp (`/tmp` ?) directory when starting up your server in integration mode.

---

Ah cool, (disclaimer: i'm not a php person) it looks like php has IO streams that may be able to help in functional testing, and allow easy cleanup.

http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#refsect2-wrappers.php-unknown-unknown-unknown-unknown-unknown-descriptios

I believe you may be able to set your 'WEB_IMAGE_UPLOAD_PATH' to be one of those streams

Comment: thank you for your piece of advice! Finally I found my way and I documented it in a dedicated answer. Feel free to comment it here below